# Where do I enqueue jobs into ActiveJob in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I am a beginner when it comes to Rails. I am trying to follow this example:

```
http://ryanselk.com/2014/09/25/using-background-jobs-in-rails-42-with-active-job/
```

It says:

"Jobs can be added to the job queue from anywhere. We can add a job to the queue by: ResizeImage.perform_later 'http://example.com/ex.png' "

[UPDATE] Sorry, I am stupid. I came up with this task:

```
namespace :simple do

  # call from command line:
  # rake simple:resize_images 

  desc "Resize images"
  task resize_images: :environment do

    Dir.foreach('storage') do |next_image|
      puts next_image
      next if next_image == '.' or next_image == '..'
      ResizeImage.perform_later next_image
    end

  end

end
```

but now I do:

```
rake simple:resize_images
```

and I get:

```
zacek2_phpP9JGif.jpg
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ResizeImage
```

I've tried:

```
require ResizeImage
```

but that did not fix the problem.

I am afraid I don't understand how loading works in Rails. How do I load ResizeImage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I set it up as a cron job?

No.

From [the rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html):

> Active Job is a framework for declaring jobs and making them run on a variety of queueing backends.

Active Job is an interface to queueing backends such as [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). It's simply a way for you to write background jobs where you don't have to care about which of the queueing backends will be used.

[image: ActiveJob Diagram]

> How do I start ActiveJob?

So ActiveJob doesn't run background jobs on it's own. You're still missing one of the backends. Say you have decided to use delayed_job: [Get it installed](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and then start it via:

```
script/delayed_job start
```

> I don't understand where "anywhere" is.

That means anywhere in your code, you could write something like:

#### user.rb

```
def send_registration_email
  UserRegistraionMailJob.perform_later self
end
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. One follow up: I have decided I will call this from a rake task. But I can not get the path to the job correct. How do I get NameError: uninitialized constant ResizeImage. How do I import the ResizeImage job to the rake task?

Comment: I have: "class ResizeImage < ActiveJob::Base" in "app/jobs/resize_image_job.rb" but how do I import ResizeImage to "./lib/tasks/simple.rake"

Comment: I have the sidekiq gem installed

Comment: Ah, I am stupid. I gave the wrong name to the file. Fixed now.